# Laravel. How to put put image from Laravel public folder and to put it into database

Tags: php, image, laravel, phpmyadmin

maybe somebody could advice me. I have images in Laravel public/images folder and now in my dishes table im trying to put image from public folder

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('dishes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unique();
        $table->string('gamintojas', 20);
        $table->text('aprasymas', 1000 );
        $table->binary('nuotrauka');
        $table->string('logotipas');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

`

and I am trying to seed it

```
public function run()
{

    DB::table('dishes')->insert([

      'gamintojas' => 'CANON',
      'aprasymas' => 'CANON EOS 750D 18-55IS STM.Be pastangų darykite aukštesnio lygio nuotraukas padedami naujausių DSLR technologijų ir išmaniojo automatinio režimo su Canon „EOS 750D“. Atraskite kūrybiškus fotografavimo kampus ir mėgaukitės paprasta, intuityvia prieiga prie valdiklių naudodami 3,0 col. (7,7 cm) kintamo kampo LCD jutiklinį ekraną. „EOS 750D“ turi išmanųjį vaizdo ieškiklį, kuris žymiai pagerina fotografavimo patirtį. Žiūrint per vaizdo ieškiklį lengviau matyti fokusuojamą tašką ir visas aktyvias automatinio fokusavimo sritis, o taip pat jame aiškiai rodoma fotografinė informacija. Galingas DIGIC 6 procesorius įgalina fotografuoti visa raiška 5 k./s sparta, tad niekada nepraleisite tos vienintelės akimirkos.',
      'nuotrauka' => file_get_contents('public/images/canon-eos-750d.jpg'),
      'logotipas' => 'canon-logo.png',
    ]);
}
```

and to show it in my blade:

```
 <ul class="list-group col-md-4 {{ $classes}}" >
   <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
    {{ $dish->gamintojas}}
   </li>
   <li class="list-group-item">
     <img src="{{ $dish->logotipas}}" class="img-responsive">
   </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
   <a href="{{  route('dishes.show', $dish->id)}}">
    <img src="{{ $dish->nuotrauka}}" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item height-fix">
    {{($dish->aprasymas) }}
 </li>
```

but after pushing "artisan migrate:refresh --seed"  I am getting error

`

[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column'nuotrauka' at row 1 `

Comment: Use `text` in place of `binary` that will solve the error as it will increase the length of data that can be put in the columns.

Comment: You can rather put your images in the `storage` folder and create a symlink to the `public` folder and then save its path in the database. That's the right way to store images.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your `'nuotrauka'` field bigger.
This error means that `'nuotrauka'` field does not have enough space.